# Github, create multiple SSH keys for a single account from different machines

Tags: git, ssh

I've setup git and successfully created the SSH key by following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) official tutorial in my `MAC`. Everything works fine.

Now I want to setup the same thing in my Windows 10 machine. But when I follow the tutorial I keep getting `permission denied (public key)`. I tried the debugging steps mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) , but no success.

Can you please help me out setting it up on windows too. Here are the debug details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions to the private key file ? It should be set to `600` -  [check here](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder)
Have you added the key to Github ?

Comment: Hi, tried to set all the permissions as you said. But still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to use separate SSH keys on each machine, to limit the pain in the event of a compromise (you only have to rekey the compromised machine, and not all of them).

To add another public key to your Github account, login to Github and then visit https://github.com/account (or click the "Account Settings" link in your dashboard), then click "SSH Public Keys" and then "Add another public key". Give the new key a title (usually the machine's name is best) and then paste the key data itself into the large textbox. From then on, you should be able to access Github repositories over SSH from either machine.

Comment: I generate a key on windows machine too. I've two separate keys in my github account i.e one for windows and the other for MAC